# Looping through array-dictionary-dictionary using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I'm trying to loop through this sample of JSON to get `age`, `name` and `type` using SwiftyJSON. I succeeded getting `name` and `age` but the `type` is hard for me. Can someone show me how to do it, please?

```
"both": [
{
  "id": 130,
  "name": "TMT",
  "age": "2006",
  "created_at": "2016-12-19 21:37:06",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-19 21:37:06",
  "pic": "1482183426.png",
  "pivot": {
    "user_id": 4,
    "car_id": 130,
    "type": "rent"
  }
},
{
  "id": 113,
  "name": "TMT ",
  "age": 2016,
  "created_at": "2016-12-18 14:46:18",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-18 14:47:41",
  "pic": "",
  "pivot": {
    "user_id": 4,
    "car_id": 113,
    "type": "rent"
  }
}
]
```

**work**

```
    let json = JSON(value)
for (key, subJson) in json {

    let cars = subJson["both"]


    for (key, subJson) in cars {

        print(subJson["age"])

}
```

Comment: The same way you're getting "name" *as String*, you have to get "pivot" *as a [String: Any] dictionary* then you can get the values from the dictionary.

Comment: this is how I get the `age`. Should I loop again ? I thought swifty-json has an easier way

`let json = JSON(value)
    for (key, subJson) in json {
        
        let cars = subJson["both"]
        
        
        for (key, subJson) in cars {
            
            print(subJson["age"])
            
    }`

Comment: look at the comment above yours please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to is to access `pivot` dictionary and read the `type` key from there.

```
let json = JSON(value)
for (key, subJson) in json {
    let cars = subJson["both"]
    for (key, subJson) in cars {
        let age = subJson["age"]
        // Access pivot dictionary
        let pivot = subJson["pivot"]
        // Get type from pivot dictionary
        let type = pivot["type"]
    }
}
```